# Picking two files from different folders and analyzing them together

Tags: macros, imagej

I'm new to imageJ and programming so forgive any rookie mistakes I'm making here, but after trawling through a number of tutorials and pages on this site I cobbled together the following macro, who's purpose is to pick two files from predetermined folders, match them together based on certain common words in the file names, and run an analysis overlaying the ROIs from one to the other. The actual analysis part works fine, what's putting a stick in my wheel is the matching of the files.

```
//Independant variables
dir1 = getDirectory("string"); //image to be ROIed
dir2 = getDirectory("string"); //image for ROI to be overlayed on (thresholded Cy3)
dir3 = getDirectory("string"); //Cy3+Alexa Data folder
list = getFileList(dir1);
list2 = getFileList(dir2);

//Recursive
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    for (n=0; n<list2.length; n++) {
    path = dir1+list[i];
    path2 = dir2+list2[n];

//Recursive-dependant variables
name = File.getName(path);
name2 = File.getName(path2); 
start1Cy = indexOf(name2, "VLPAG") * indexOf(name2, "R"); 
start2Cy = (indexOf(name2, "VLPAG") * indexOf(name2, "L")) - 1;
start3Cy = (indexOf(name2, "LPAG") * indexOf(name2, "R")) - 2;
start4Cy = (indexOf(name2, "LPAG") * indexOf(name2, "L")) - 3;
start1Al = (indexOf(name, "VLPAG") * indexOf(name, "R")) - 4; 
start2Al = (indexOf(name, "VLPAG") * indexOf(name, "L")) - 5;
start3Al = (indexOf(name, "LPAG") * indexOf(name, "R")) - 6;
start4Al = (indexOf(name, "LPAG") * indexOf(name, "L")) - 7;
start1 = (start1Cy*start1Al);
start2 = (start2Cy*start2Al);
start3 = (start3Cy*start3Al);
start4 = (start4Cy*start4Al);

//Generate ROIs from Alexa images
open(path); {
    run("Set Measurements...", "area mean min area_fraction redirect=None decimal=3");
    run("Analyze Particles...", "  show=Nothing clear add");
}
//Apply ROIs to Cy3 and measure
open(path2); 
if (start1==20160) {
    run("From ROI Manager");
    run("Measure");
    roiManager("delete");
    selectWindow("Results");
    saveAs("results", dir3 + name + name2 + " colocalized.csv");
    run("Clear Results");
    selectWindow("Results");
    run("Close");
} else if (start2==19877) {
    run("From ROI Manager");
    run("Measure");
    roiManager("delete");
    selectWindow("Results");
    saveAs("results", dir3 + name + name2 + " colocalized.csv");
    run("Clear Results");
    selectWindow("Results");
    run("Close");
} else if (start3==19596) {
    run("From ROI Manager");
    run("Measure");
    roiManager("delete");
    selectWindow("Results");
    saveAs("results", dir3 + name + name2 + " colocalized.csv");
    run("Clear Results");
    selectWindow("Results");
    run("Close");
} else if (start4==19317) {
    run("From ROI Manager");
    run("Measure");
    roiManager("delete");
    selectWindow("Results");
    saveAs("results", dir3 + name + name2 + " colocalized.csv");
    run("Clear Results");
    selectWindow("Results");
    run("Close");
} else {
    close("*");
    }
}
}
close("*");
selectWindow("ROI Manager");
run("Close");
```

The macro runs to completion without errors, but only produces results files for half of the images, the ones labeled LPAG. I've tried reformatting in various ways to get around naming the files the same thing etc but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing what the filenames are that you are trying to match it is difficult to help. I suspect that for the images where you don't get results, they don't match your condition start1, start2 etc. so they are getting closed. As your code stands right now, each of the if-else-if statements does the same thing, so I don't see what you are trying to do with that.

Comment: It is always a good idea to code step-by-step. Although you write that the core function is working correctly, just leave it out and create a macro that does only the file-handling. Start with a simple version that uses a single input and a single output directory. If this works, add the second input directory and so on. Always check with print staements that the files you open are the correct ones. Do the same with the directory paths.